# Missing or invalid type argument for pointer action - Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I am getting below mentioned error message while run program.

> Error: Missing or invalid type argument for pointer action.

I am trying to click on sub menu which will display after mouse hover on main menu.

Code below:

```
public class ActionKeywords {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    @Test
    public void openBrowser(){
        driver.get("https://www.levissima.it/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    @Test
    public void verify_Menus(){

        WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='menu-main']/li/a"));

        WebElement subMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Impegno Per La Natura')]"));
        Actions action = new Actions (driver);
        action.moveToElement(mainMenu).perform();
        action.click(subMenu).perform();
    }
}
```

Please assist!

Comment: which line throws you this error; add complete error stacktrace.

Comment: At which line are you seeing the error? Please provide full error stack trace.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Missing or invalid type argument for pointer action
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
System info: host: 'M3B-D-543T2D3', ip: '192.168.91.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Selenium 3.4.0 to work with Mozilla Firefox browser 53.x you need to download the latest geckodriver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Save it in your machine & provide the absolute path of the geckodriver. This code executes fine with some simple tweak to your own code.

```
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public void setup()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
    driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@Test
public void openBrowser(){
    driver.get("https://www.levissima.it/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
@Test
public void verify_Menus(){

    WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='menu-main']/li/a"));

    WebElement subMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Impegno Per La Natura')]"));
    Actions action = new Actions (driver);
    action.moveToElement(mainMenu).perform();
    action.click(subMenu).perform();
}
```

The output is:

```
PASSED: openBrowser
PASSED: verify_Menus

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor

Comment: 1. Which version of Selenium are you using? 2. Are you using gecko driver? 3. If so which version? 4. What is your Mozilla Firefox Browser version?

Comment: Selenium 3.3.1
Firefox 53.0

Comment: Done! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

One better way to achieve this `click()` would be :

```
    Actions action = new Actions (driver);
    action.moveToElement(mainMenu).moveToElement(subMenu).click().build().perform();
```

This is called chaining of actions.

Comment: Yes . Kushal. But still, I am getting the same error as org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Missing or invalid type argument for pointer action

Comment: import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

Comment: this will not solve anything. MoveTo only works when you are automating some new and fancy javascript UI which requires the element to be focused to be "clickable". This problem is a bug between versions. You must use the proper geckodriver to your set of Firefox and Selenium. At least one should work.

Answer (score 0):

I got that error today, and solved it just using another geckodriver version. In that case (Firefox 52 + Selenium 3.8.0 ), geckodriver 0.15 solved it.

Is not the first time im forced to download and try different versions of Firefox/Geckodriver/Selenium.

Downloading the latest geckodriver will not solve problems by defaults. You may need an older version according to your Firefox and geckodriver versions, so, don't hesitate to try on your own instead of just get the latest version hoping it will magically work.

I really recommend try different geckodrivers before become crazy.