# InvalidArgumentexception while locating a webelement by dynamic xPath

Tags: selenium, xpath, dynamic

I wish to mouse hover "Books & More"in Flipkart and view the dropdown list.
Used the code as below:

```
WebElement Booksxpath=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Books & More']"));
actions.moveToElement(Booksxpath).build().perform();
```

Code is giving the error:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentexception:Missing 'type' parameter

Comment: You might wanna check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732028/missing-or-invalid-type-argument-for-pointer-action-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

> Ensure that you take help of the **`Actions`** class and use **`import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;`** only

The following code block will browse to `https://www.flipkart.com/` and will **`Mouse Hover`** over **`BOOKS & MORE`** and you can view the dropdown list:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Q45262660_Flipcart_MouseHover 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        WebElement Booksxpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Books & More']"));
        Actions act = new Actions (driver);
        act.moveToElement(Booksxpath).perform();
    }

}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Actually I downloaded the latest Gecko driver and it solved the problem.